# html table with relative position should be visible on horizontal scroll bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have html structure like:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="11">                        
      <table style="vertical-align: middle; width=100%;" id="myInnerTable">
        <tr>
          <td align="right">Some controls</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id=”myOuterTableTR”>
    ... more columns ...
  <tr>
  ... more rows ...
</table>
```

When there is no horizontal scroll bar "Some controls" are aligned to the right as expected and are visible. But when there is a horizontal scroll bar, "Some controls" go to the extreme right side and they are not visible and the user has to scroll extreme right to see them.

I would like to have them visible on the screen even if there is a horizontal scroll bar and should not have to scroll right to see them.

I tried to give “myInnerTable” table a fixed position but in that case, the layout of the page gets disturbed like controls from next tr tag `myOuterTableTR` overlap with `myInnerTable` controls. So I think I need to have `myInnerTable` position as relative only.

I think I need to write some JavaScript and check if there is any horizontal scroll bar then add some right-margin/space to `myInnerTable` so that it will be visible without scrolling.

Also, I am not using JavaScript.

Comment: Your style attribute for your inner table has no ending quote(") mark. It runs into the width="100%" attribute.

Comment: And some of your quotation marks are curly (`&rdquo;`) instead of straight(`"`).  These are not the same characters